# Delete contents of array based on a set of indexes

Tags: ruby

delete_at only takes a single index. What's a good way to achieve this using built-in methods?
Doesn't have to be a set, can be an array of indexes as well.

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
set = Set.new [1, 2]
arr.delete_at set
# => arr = ["a"]
```

Comment: must be necessarily an in-place modification?

Comment: I take it you're using the Set type in `Set.new` to ensure uniqueness, rather than just using another array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One-liner:

```
arr.delete_if.with_index { |_, index| set.include? index }
```

Comment: Just a note, since it's hard to search for `_` underscore symbol - it's a placeholder that is commonly used if you're going to just ignore the index.  The `_` is a valid variable, but the code line isn't going anything with it.

Answer (score 6):

Re-open the Array class and add a new method for this.

```
class Array

  def delete_at_multi(arr)
    arr = arr.sort.reverse # delete highest indexes first.
    arr.each do |i|
      self.delete_at i
    end
    self
  end

end

arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
set = [1, 2]

arr.delete_at_multi(set)

arr # => ["a"]
```

This could of course be written as a stand-alone method if you don't want to re-open the class. Making sure the indexes are in reverse order is very important, otherwise you change the position of elements later in the array that are supposed to be deleted.

Comment: +1, but *delete_at_indices* would be a better name: it preserves the readability of delete_at, but still  makes it obvious that it takes multiple indices.  As far as readability, you might say "delete at 3" or "delete at indices 3, 5, and 7" but you wouldn't say "delete at multi 3, 5, and 7".   (And of course, for those who aren't pedantic about using the word "indices", there could be an alias *delete_at_indexes* ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
arr.reject { |item| set.include? arr.index(item) }  # => [a]
```

It's a bit ugly, I think ;) Maybe someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: A simple solution for my problem, while others failed!

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach:

```
class Array
  def except_values_at(*indexes)
    ([-1] + indexes + [self.size]).sort.each_cons(2).flat_map do |idx1, idx2|
      self[idx1+1...idx2] || []
    end
  end
end

>> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].except_values_at(1, 3)
=> ["a", "c", "e"]
```