# Remove array elements at indices non destructively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say you have something like this:

```
my_array = ['some_rather', 'long_named', 'array_element', 'entry']
```

I want to remove arbitrary entries by index from my_array without changing it and I want the filtered (i.e. array with indices removed) to be returned from my call. Furthermore, I want to avoid chaining 4 separate calls and write a block doing so.

Example:

```
filtered_array = my_array.drop_indices(1,3)
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964543/delete-contents-of-array-based-on-a-set-of-indexes

Comment: _"I want to avoid chaining 4 separate calls"_ – in addition you'd have to remove the indices highest to lowest.

Comment: @Deep First: I didn't find that related post. Second: It doesn't specify non destructively and therefore is not completely redundant. Third: My question is more concise and readable as the other question.

Comment: @Ekkstein Yes but it has multiple options which can be converted to non destructive mode. And mainly it has an option to add the method to `Array` class itself which would be exact what you want with the `drop_indices` method. You will have to mix two or three answers to acheive the best solution but those are just options if you like (I didn't say that your question is duplicate or something).

Answer (score 2):

You could chain Enumerable's [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) onto Array's [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject) method to do what you want, though this might violate your desire to not chain separate method calls or write a block to do this:

```
my_array = ['some_rather', 'long_named', 'array_element', 'entry', 'long_named']
indices_to_remove = [1, 3]

filtered = my_array.reject.with_index { |_, index| indices_to_remove.include?(index) }

p filtered # => ["some_rather", "array_element", "long_named"]
p my_array # => ["some_rather", "long_named", "array_element", "entry", "long_named"]
```

If this isn't acceptable, the only other thing I can think of right now, to keep duplicate items (as noted in my comment to your solution), is to change from `indices_to_remove` to `indices_to_keep`:

```
my_array = ['some_rather', 'long_named', 'array_element', 'entry', 'long_named']
indices_to_remove = [1, 3]
indices_to_keep = [*(0...my_array.length)] - indices_to_remove

filtered = my_array.values_at(*indices_to_keep)
p filtered # => ["some_rather", "array_element", "long_named"]
p my_array # => ["some_rather", "long_named", "array_element", "entry", "long_named"]
```

Comment: Yeah, I touched those as well. I found that to be too much writing for a simple task...

Comment: I'll wait in case another answer shows up, if not, I'll vote your answer as accepted.

Comment: Ekkstein, still waiting?

Answer (score 0):

**For Arrays with duplicate Elements the best I know is:**

```
array = [0,15,8,15,8]
indices_to_remove = [1,4]
res = array.reject.with_index{ |_,i| indices_to_remove.include?(i) }
```

returns

```
[0,8,15]
```

---

**Additionally for arrays with unique entries such as a set of users**

*(using variable definitions from the question)*

```
filtered_array = my_array - my_array.values_at(1,3)
```

Bonus, if your indices are inside an array themselves:

```
indices_to_remove = [1,3]
filtered_array = my_array - my_array.values_at(*indices_to_remove)
```

I think this is rather descriptive, not awkward and not shorter than needed.

Comment: with `my_array = ['some_rather', 'long_named', 'array_element', 'entry', 'long_named']` (note the second 'long_named' at the end), this solution gives you a `filter_array` of `["some_rather", "array_element"]`, which may or may not be what you want

Comment: Answers that have been shown to be incorrect should be removed. The second part of your answer is correct, however, and is not limited to arrays that contain duplicates. I therefore suggest you remove the lines up to and including, “For Arrays with duplicate Elements the best I know is:” and possibly add a sentence defining the two arrays. If you wish you could move the first part to your question (“I tried the following, but it gives an incorrect result when the array contains duplicates...”). The first sentence is irrelevant and of no interest to readers, so it should be dropped.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you, I mostly adapted your suggestions. My intend is to provide extra information aiming for users with varying experience.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution with some addition, now it's also will work with negative indexes:

```
array = %w( a b c d e f )
indexes = [1, 2, -1, -9, -6, 6]

def array_except(array, *indexes)
  indexes = indexes.map { |e| e.negative? ? e + array.length : e }
  array.values_at(*((0...array.length).to_a - indexes))
end

array_except(array, *indexes)
=> ["d", "e"]
array_except(array, 0, -1)
=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
```